# how to execute multiple sqls in bigquery with minimum db hits

Tags: python, google-bigquery

we have requirement, where we have bunch of SQLs in data frame and want to execute in BQ. if data is return by that query then want to set flag Y else N in data frame. is there any way to execute multiple sentence in BQ- in one go i.e. with single hit to BQ

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple SQL statements to a single script using semi-colons.

```
SELECT 1;
SELECT 2;
SELECT 3;
```

Running that script as opposed to three separate scripts will reduce your API call count but won't necessarily limit your BQ read costs. You will need to provide more information on your SQL and potentially refactor that in order to reduce read costs.